# Jenkins installation and configuration on Gcp without exposing the public ip of the VM's

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

Use case: I wish to install a Jenkins master/slave setup on GCP.

Restrictions: The VM's are not allowed to have any public ip's associated to them. They are in a private VPC that consists of 1 public and 1 private subnet.

I was able to install Jenkins on the VM however, I am unable to view it from the browser. Any suggestions around this?

Comment: What you get when you try http://internal_IP_of_VM:8080. Check your firewall also. Also test locally if everything is working and by that i mean do a curl internalip:8080 and check if you get a 200 response. Isolate then issue first. Is it my vm? Browser? or firewall?

Comment: If your VM haven't public IP, you can't see it except if you have access to the private IP (if you are connected through VPN for example). The other solution is to set a Load Balancer in front of your VM to make it accessible from the internet. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @guillaumeI blaquiere would like to understand how to set up a load balancer in front of the VM.

Comment: @dany L i would like to have a load balancer to allow ingress to the single VM there.